# Is it possible to blacklist subfolders in Banshee?

Tags: 11.04, banshee

I am using djmount to mount upnp music folders and then import from them into Banshee. Unfortunately, i set up the server in a way that for each artist there is an --All-- subfolder containing all the songs for that artist. This causes all songs to be imported twice into Banshee.

Is there a way to solve this without reconfiguring the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a smart playlist (*Media → New Smart Playlist...*) matching all songs which filepaths (*File Location* from the dropdown menu) contain *--All--* and then remove all those songs from the library. Definitely not the best solution.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. It is a good enough solution for me.